# Uploading a discord bot (python) onto Heroku : App not compatible with buildpack error (I know its been asked a lot)

Tags: python, mongodb, github, heroku, discord.py

I'm currently trying to create a discord bot (in python) and having created a working local version, I want to upload it onto Heroku.

I've opted to connect it through github so I can push changes and have it automatically update, as opposed to going through the heroku github method of pushing changes.

I've been searching for an answer but nothing I do is helping. I admit I am quite new to this so maybe I have made a really silly mistake.

Every time I try to deploy branch I get the error that the App is not compatible with buildpack, I've tried every fix I could find online and have even tried the heroku github method of pushing changes using the heroku CLI, but nothing is working.

My repository currently consists of:

Bot.py (the discord bot script)

Procfile

```
worker: python Bot.py
```

Requirements.txt

```
pymongo==3.10.1
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.8
```

I experimented getting rid of pymongo in case that was causing the issue, but getting rid of it + removing everything in the in the bot script itself that referred to it, but I still get the same error.

I am using the python buildpack and the full error I get is

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

 !     Push failed
```

I have added two add-ons onto my app using the web-app (postgres and mLab) as I suspect I will want to use them as alternatives to my current setup for MongoDB access.

Perhaps I've done something silly but if anyone could help I would be really thankful!

Comment: Is your file actually called `Requirements.txt`, with a capital `R`, or `requirements.txt`? Is it in the root directory of your project?

Comment: Aaaa you're right, even though I changed R to r locally and pushed it to github, it actually didn't update on github itself.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about you add discord.py to your `requirements.txt` because i can't see it there, it will build but can't run the bot.

```
discord.py==1.4.1
```

Heroku supports [pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html), You can make the environment in your local machine at the same root directory so when you push to GitHub the environment files are there. no need for `requirements.txt`. [Basic guide](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/#pipenv-introduction)